# Ansible launch ssh-copy-id before running play?

Tags: ansible

I want to use Ansible to disable selinux in some remote servers. I don't know yet the full list of the servers, it will come from time to time.

That would be great if the `ssh-copy-id` phase would be integrated somehow in the playbook - you would expect that from an automation system ? I don't mind getting asked for the password one time per server.

With various reading, I understand I can run a `local_action` in my task:

```
---
  - name: Disable SELinux
    hosts: all
    remote_user: root
    gather_facts: False
    tasks:
    - local_action: command ssh-copy-id {{remote_user}}@{{hostname}}
    - selinux:
        state: disabled
```

However:

- It fails because `{{remote_user}}` and `{{hostname}}` are not accessible in this context.
- I need to `gather_facts`to `False`, because it's executed before `local_action`

Any idea if that's possible within Ansible playbooks ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this:

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        rem_user: "{{ ansible_user | default(lookup('env','USER')) }}"
        rem_host: "{{ ansible_host }}"
    - local_action: command ssh-copy-id {{ rem_user }}@{{ rem_host }}
    - setup:
    - selinux:
        state: disabled
```

Define remote user and remote host first, then make local action, then enforce fact gathering with `setup`.

Comment: That's working great. Any explanation why we cannot access `{{ ansible_host }}` directly ?

Comment: ansible_host is overriden when used with local_action.

Comment: How to deal with the remote host key changed in `~/.ssh/known_hosts`

Comment: `ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=false ansible-playbook ...`

Comment: Why did you have to include `gather_facts: no`?